# Accessing C++ template class in cython

Tags: python, c++, templates, cython

I have a template class called `List` defined in a file called `containers.h`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


namespace containers {
    template <class T> class List {
        private:
            std::vector<T> vector;
        public:
            List() {};
            ~List() {};
            void append(T* item) {
                vector.push_back(*item);
            }
            void print_items() {
                for ( T item : vector ) {
                    std::cout << item << std::endl;
                }
            }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to import this class into Cython using this code in `main.pyx`:

```
#!python
# cython: language_level = 3
# distutils: language = c++


cdef extern from "containers.h" namespace "containers":
    cdef cppclass List[T]:
        List() except +
        void append(T *item)
        void print_items()


def test():
    cdef List[int] *l = new List[int]()
    cdef int i
    for i in range(10):
        l.append(&i)
    l.print_items()
```

And this is what happens when I try to run this code:

```
>>> import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/arin/Desktop/Misc/test_cpp/main.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10containers4ListIiEC1Ev
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Probably the most relevant answer from dupe https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/5769463: constructor isn’t defined

Comment: The code as presented here compiles and runs perfectly for me (which makes sense because you have defined the constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a silly mistake in compiling: in `setup.py` I passed `"main.cpp"` into the `cythonize` function instead of `"main.pyx"`, and it didn't cause errors while compiling because I had another file called `main.cpp`.